# Concurrent Queries, COPY and Connections in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to understand the difference between concurrent connections and concurrent queries in Redshift. As per documents, We can make 500 concurrent connections to a Redshift cluster but it says maximum 15 queries can be run at the same time in a cluster. Now what is the exact value?

1. How many queries can be in running state in a cluster at the same time ? If it is 15, does it include RETURNING state queries as well ?
2. How many concurrent COPY statement can run in a cluster ?

We are evaluating Redshift as our primary reporting data store. If we cannot run a large number of queries simultaneously it may be difficult for us to go with this model.

Comment: Don't know much about redshift but I'd say that when you connect to a cluster your query will be queued some how, and that's why you can have 500 concurrent connections but only 15 concurrent queries.
[Check this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you have misread somewhere, Max concurrent queries are 50 per WLM. Refer below [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232113) for Amazon support response for more detail.

> How many queries can be in running state in a cluster at the same time ? If it is 15, does it include RETURNING state queries as well ?

At a time, Max 50 queries could be running concurrently. Yes it does include INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE etc all.

> How many concurrent COPY statement can run in a cluster ?

Ideally, you could Max go up to 50 concurrently, but Copy works bit differently.

[Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-single-copy-command.html) automatically loads in parallel from multiple data files.

If you use multiple concurrent COPY commands to load one table from multiple files, Amazon Redshift is forced to perform a serialized load, which is much slower and requires a VACUUM at the end if the table has a sort column defined. For more information about using COPY to load data in parallel, see Loading Data from Amazon S3.

Meaning, you could run concurrent `Copy` commands but make sure one copy command at a time per table.

So practically, it doesn't depend on Nodes on cluster, but Number of tables as well.
So if you have only 1 table, you would like to execute 50 insert concurrently, it will result only 1 Copy concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  However, **WLM Concurrency** is different from **Queries in Running State** at same time. _WLM Concurrency_ is number of slots you can set in cluster's User Defined Queues, which can be upto 50. In the thread you mentioned, that also explains about Concurrency Level not _Number of Queries Running at same time_

Comment: @DeepanshuRai, could you please locate me the link on Redshift documentation that say `15 concurrent` queries. I think its guideline to not go beyond `15` overall. And its `15` Max limit per `WLM`, but with Multiple WLM Group you could up to `50` in aggreation, but not go beyond `50`.